# problems with large DLL?

Tags: .net

Are there any problems associated with using and deploying large DLLs? I'm using a couple of DLLs that's 30Mb and 17Mb in size.

Comment: what are the problems that you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mitch says, no.

In fact it is actually recommended by Microsoft to create a smaller number of larger sized assemblies over many small assemblies.  [This earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337144/does-net-assembly-size-affect-performance) provides very useful information and references.

In your case you should definitely test the load times and keep the size within acceptable limits, but it seems there are more problems associated with creating numerous small assemblies then a few large ones.

Answer (score 2):

Other than load time and download time, no.