# What are the Drawbacks of large binaries?

Tags: language-agnostic, dll

I ask since a project I work on generates a single, monolithic DLL of about 50 MB size.

Does a large library like this one impede performance, or can it bring other gotchas?

UPDATE:
I work with Embercadero RAD Studio Delphi 2010 on Windows (XP|Vista|7).

Comment: depends to an extent on the environment and platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, you should prefer a few large assemblies rather than many small assemblies.

See: [Does .NET assembly size affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337144/does-net-assembly-size-affect-performance)